# Listview child should link to another child

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I created an expandable listview based on [this](http://learnandroideasily.blogspot.in/2013/07/android-expandablelistview-example.html) link. Its just working fine. Now what i want is

1) How to make a childview to link another sub-child view

2) The sub- child view should be open as a new list view on the window(Right side of the view) [image: here] is my expected layout. I googled but couldn't find how to achieve this. Please help me in achieving this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please explain more deeply what are you trying to achieve? Do you want to visualize all three views together on the screen or you want a new activity for each child view you open?

Comment: @RobertoLombardini is my question clear now?

Comment: It's a lot more clear and but also a lot more complex than what i  thought

Answer (score 0):

So, do you want your first child to expand into another ListView? Or maybe just open another Activity/Fragment that contains the matching ListView?

In case you want to the the first, you could design a CustomLayout for the Childview, which on OnClick expands, and changes its content to a specific ListView.

Otherwise you would just open up another ListView with data depending on Which Child in First List was Clicked.

Well, i am using some Like that to enlarge ChildViews on Click to show me detailed information.

Im using a Class to wrap my Data named Row. These Rows indicate if they are clickable and if so, the ListView will allow clicks on the rows. A Click will then be handled by the Class itself, making the displayed Text longer(more Detailed). And in order to relayout the items, you need to call notifyDataSetChanged.

```
@Override
public void onClick(Context context, MyExpandableListAdapter mela) {
    this.setBig(!isBig());
    mela.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

So, i would handle the row state (expanded/normal) in the getView Method of parents Adapter, to decide which childLayout i inflate.

would looke something like this

```
public View getView (args...) {
 Object data = getItem(position);

 if (data.isExpanded()) {
    //inflate ListView Layout, create Addapter fill it....
 } else {
    //show some title or whatever to identify row.
 }
}
```

Comment: i want the childview to expand another list activity and the new activity should be at the rightside of previous activity as shown in above pic.. Can u give me an example of this

Comment: updated my answer with some sample code. It would be too much to work it all out, but this should give you an idea about how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to specify and handle `onClick` event of `ListView` row items.
Then you'll open a new `Activity`, based on the item clicked.
Parameters for new activity are supplied through intent extras, the new activity can use these values to get data from cloud or process the values to show certain results.

I've used `CustomAdapter` class several times to handle this scenario.

```
class Ocl implements OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intDetail = new Intent(getActivity(), PartDetail.class);                 
        intDetail.putExtra(_ID, mParts[position].getSPr());                                     
        intDetail.putExtra(_LOT, mParts[position].getLotID());
        intDetail.putExtra(_QTY, mParts[position].getQty());
        intDetail.putExtra(_UID, mParts[position].getPartID());

        startActivity(intDetail);
    }

}
```